# javascript Function not being called for every row

Tags: javascript, node.js, reverse-geocoding

I am having something like:

```
<div id="list_event" class="row">
<div class="panel panel-primary filterable">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Evénements</h3>
        <div class="pull-right" style="margin-top:-6px">
            <span class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-filter"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter"></span> Filter</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered" id="table_event">
        <thead>
            <tr class="filters">
                <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Titre" disabled></th>
                <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Description" disabled></th>
                <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Date de début" disabled></th>
                <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Date de fin" disabled></th>
                <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type" disabled></th>
                <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Lieu" disabled></th>
                <th>Type d'alerte</th>
                <th>Statut</th>
                <th style="display:none">#</th>
                <th class="tabledit-toolbox-column"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <% for(var i=0; i<listEvent.length; i++) {%>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tabledit-view-mode"><span class="tabledit-span"><%- listEvent[i].title %></span><input class="tabledit-input form-control input-sm" type="text" name="title" value="<%- listEvent[i].title %>" style="display: none;" disabled=""></td>

                    <td class="tabledit-view-mode"><span class="tabledit-span"><%- listEvent[i].description %></span><input class="tabledit-input form-control input-sm" type="text" name="description" value="<%- listEvent[i].description %>" style="display: none;" disabled=""></td>

                    <td class="tabledit-view-mode"><span class="tabledit-span"><%- listEvent[i].startDate %></span><input class="tabledit-input form-control input-sm" type="text" name="startDate" value="<%- listEvent[i].startDate %>" style="display: none;" disabled=""></td>

                    <td class="tabledit-view-mode"><span class="tabledit-span"><%- listEvent[i].endDate %></span><input class="tabledit-input form-control input-sm" type="text" name="endDate" value="<%- listEvent[i].endDate %>" style="display: none;" disabled=""></td>

                    <td class="tabledit-view-mode"><span class="tabledit-span"><%- listEvent[i].type %></span><input class="tabledit-input form-control input-sm" type="text" name="type" value="<%- listEvent[i].type %>" style="display: none;" disabled=""></td>

                    <td class="place"><%- listEvent[i].place %></td>

                    <td>
                        <ul>
                            <% for(var j=0; j<listEvent[i].typesAlert.length; j++) {%>
                                <li><%- listEvent[i].typesAlert[j].name %></li>
                            <% } %>
                        </ul>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <%
                        if (listEvent[i].state == 1) {%>
                            <span class="label label-warning">En cours</span>
                        <%}
                        if (listEvent[i].state == 2) {%>
                            <span class="label label-success">Validé</span>
                        <%}
                        if (listEvent[i].state == 3) {%>
                            <span class="label label-danger">Bloqué</span>
                        <%}%>
                    </td>
                    <td scope="row" style="display:none"><%- listEvent[i].id %></td>

                    <td style="white-space: nowrap; width: 1px;">
                        <div class="tabledit-toolbox" style="margin-left: -5px; text-align: right;">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <% } %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var geocoder;
$(function geocode (){
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var coordinates = document.getElementsByClassName("place");
    for (var i=0; i<coordinates.length; i++) {
        coordinates[i].id = coordinates[i].innerHTML;
        retrieveAddress(coordinates[i], coordinates[i].innerHTML);
    }
});

function retrieveAddress(coordinate, input) {
    var latlngStr = input.split(";",2);
    var lat = parseFloat(latlngStr[0]);
    var lng = parseFloat(latlngStr[1]);
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && results[0]) {
            coordinate.innerHTML = results[0].formatted_address;

        }
    });
}
</script>
<script src="/js/jquery.tabledit.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#table_event').Tabledit({
    url: '/event/tableEdit',
    columns: {
        identifier: [7, 'id'],
        editable: [[0, 'title'],[1, 'description'],[2, 'startDate'],[3, 'endDate'],[4, 'type']]
    },
    buttons: {
        edit: {
            class: 'tabledit-edit-button btn btn-sm btn-warning',
            html: '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>',
            action: 'edit'
        },
        delete: {
            class:'tabledit-remove-button btn btn-sm btn-danger tabledit-confirm',
            action: 'delete'
        },
        confirm: {
            class: 'btn btn-sm btn-danger',
            html: '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Supprimer'
        },
        restore: {
            class: 'btn btn-sm btn-warning',
            html: '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-download"></span> Restaurer',
            action: 'restore'
        },
        save: {
            class: 'btn btn-sm btn-success',
            html: '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Sauvegarder'
        },
    },
});
</script>
```

The problem is that the function **geocode** work just for the  first five rows and for the rest not being called(my geocode function allows to get readable address or place name from point location (latitude, longitude))
[this is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMfyc.png)

Comment: according to the documentation, google limit the requests to 50 requests per second - now, that's all well and good, but does that mean you can make 50 requests in 100ms, then wait 900ms? that's not clear - maybe it's googles rate limit that is effecting you - perhaps you need to limit your requests to 1 every 20ms

Comment: although, to be honest, I really don't like the code that does `coordinates[i].id = coordinates[i].innerHTML;`

Comment: Hey  Jaromanda, thanks for the fast response!
In fact, I got an warning that says 'NoApiKeys', at first I thought because of that my code doesn't work, but even after I added The key the problem still the same and about the number I didn't exceed 17 requests in an hour :p 
So, there is something else that prevents that code to run well.          And about "coordinates[i].id = coordinates[i].innerHTML;" are you suggesting that I add an intermediate variable?! in any case, this changes nothing.

Anyway, Thanks again for answering my first question here :)

Comment: `I didn't exceed 17 requests in an hour` - yes I understand that, but how many requests are you sending at a time in `function geocode`